# Are Binaural Beats really effective?

Tags: binaural-beats

Lately, I've become quite interested in the supposed benefits that binaural beats may provide, which are summarized quite well in this article:

**https://www.webmd.com/balance/what-are-binaural-beats**

Being the skeptic that I am, I tried to find any sort of evidence online so that I could be certain of its effectiveness, but the studies are quite old, and their results were inconclusive.

So my question is: Are there any **recent** studies that give conclusive results about the effectiveness of binaural beats?

Edit: Before someone points out, yes, i've seen this post: [Is there scientific evidence on the benefits of binaural beats?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/8371/is-there-scientific-evidence-on-the-benefits-of-binaural-beats)

But this post above is quite old, with all comments being 7 to 8 years old. What i wish to have is **recent conclusions** (not inconclusions) about this topic.

Comment: I don't think we want to get in the business of rehashing every post here every few years. People can post new answers to old questions if something changes, but unless you have some support for resurfacing a question besides elapsed time, it seems best to just let the existing Q&A stand.